# Spring: Make ServeltDispatcher Context await until another Context finish loading

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I would like to load `DBbuildServletDispatcher`, after finishing **Context** loading, eg on  `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` event fire message to build(or proceed building) `AppServletDispatcher` **Context**

[image: SpringMultiDisp]

In other words could `AppDispatcher Context` wait until finishing creation of `DBbuild Context`? Are there any common ways of doing this?

Comment: You can mark App context as a child of DB context. I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do, but App context would definitely wait for DB then.

Comment: You need to add <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> for DBbuild Context and <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> for AppDispatcher Context in your web.xml to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simple. Remember the param scope is of two types - context param and servlet's init param. What you need is all dependencies must be initialised before the child context is loaded. Here `DBbuildServletDispatcher` should be initialised in the parent context, that is **ApplicationContext**, and `AppServletDispatcher` is **WebApplicationContext** which is the child context of the application context

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/DBbuildServletDispatcher.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>



<servlet>
    <servlet-name>firstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/AppServletDispatcher.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/abc/* </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The first part with context param loads the context file and create the ApplicationContext. The second part defines the WebApplicationContext.
Refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) and [WebApplicationContextUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html) may also be utilized.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work.  You load only the DBbuildContext.xml (applicationContext.xml)

after adding this line:

```
<bean id="eventListenerBean" class="a.b.c.ApplicationListenerBean" />
```

Then, define a class

```
package a.b.c;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;

public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appServletContext.xml");

        }
    }
}
```

Now the appServletContext.xml will only create a context when the dbBuildContext.xml has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just like any normal WebServlet, the instantiation of dispatcher servlets can be ordered in web.xml using `<load-on-startup>`

Looking at the [servlet 2.5 web.xml xsd](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd)

> The load-on-startup element indicates that this servlet should be
>   loaded (instantiated and have its init() called) on the startup of the
>   web application. The optional contents of these element must be an
>   integer indicating the order in which the servlet should be loaded. If
>   the value is a negative integer, or the element is not present, the
>   container is free to load the servlet whenever it chooses. If the
>   value is a positive integer or 0, the container must load and
>   initialize the servlet as the application is deployed. The container
>   must guarantee that servlets marked with lower integers are loaded
>   before servlets marked with higher integers. The container may choose
>   the order of loading of servlets with the same load-on-start-up value.

So inorder for the `DBbuildServletDispatcher` to be loaded first, make sure that its `load-on-startup` is lesser than the `load-on-startup` of `AppServletDispatcher`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DBbuildServletDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.DBbuildServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AppServletDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.AppServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```